# How to create a date range on specific dates for each month in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a start date and and end date and I would like to have the date range between start and end, on a specific day (e.g the 10th day of every month)
Example:

```
start_date = '2020-01-03'
end_date = '2020-10-19'

wanted_result = ['2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10',...,'2020-10-10', '2020-10-19']
```

I currently have a solution which creates all the dates between start_date and end_date and then subsamples only the dates on the 10th, but I do not like it, I think it is too cumbersome. Any ideas?

```
import pandas as pd
querydate = 10
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
dates = dates[[0]].append(dates[dates.day == querydate])
```

Comment: You can try finding the first and last date that fulfills your condition, and then use `pd.date_range(start='2020-01-10', end='2020-10-10', freq='1M')`.

Comment: Do I undertand correct if `start_date = '2020-01-10'
end_date = '2020-10-10'` then need this values only once? Or need double times `2020-01-10, 2020-01-10,2020-02-10...2020-10-10,2020-10-10` ?

Comment: only once! Thank you for your help @jez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If need also get first and last value add [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) by last and first value - so get all values unique, not duplicates if first or last day is `10`:

```
dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
dates = dates[dates.isin(dates[[0,-1]]) | (dates.day == querydate)]

print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10',
               '2020-04-10', '2020-05-10', '2020-06-10', '2020-07-10',
               '2020-08-10', '2020-09-10', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-19'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

If need list:

```
print (list(dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))
['2020-01-03', '2020-01-10', '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10', 
 '2020-04-10', '2020-05-10', '2020-06-10', '2020-07-10', 
 '2020-08-10', '2020-09-10', '2020-10-10', '2020-10-19']
```

Changed sample data:

```
start_date = '2020-01-10'
end_date = '2020-10-10'
querydate = 10

dates = pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date)
dates = dates[dates.isin(dates[[0,-1]]) | (dates.day == querydate)]

print (dates)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-01-10', '2020-02-10', '2020-03-10', '2020-04-10',
               '2020-05-10', '2020-06-10', '2020-07-10', '2020-08-10',
               '2020-09-10', '2020-10-10'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
```

Comment: if he wants strings so maybe this: `list(dates.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is similar to my line of thinking. I was hoping there is a more straightforward approach but seems not to be the case in Python!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dates = pd.Series([pd.to_datetime(start_date)] + [i for i in pd.date_range(start=start_date, end=end_date) if i.day == 10] + [pd.to_datetime(end_date)]).drop_duplicates()
print(dates)
```

Output:

```
    0    2020-01-03
1    2020-01-10
2    2020-02-10
3    2020-03-10
4    2020-04-10
5    2020-05-10
6    2020-06-10
7    2020-07-10
8    2020-08-10
9    2020-09-10
10   2020-10-10
11   2020-10-19
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: @jezrael What you mean?

Comment: Last values will be same.

Comment: @jezraelI Update my answer

Comment: also missing start date

Comment: unfortunately not.

Comment: @check my answer - second data for see it.

Comment: hmmm, rather I ask OP in comments, maybe it is necessary.

Comment: set? Changing order? I think it is bad, order is for datetimes always necessary.

Comment: Thank you @U11-Forward,  it is in a way similar to what I have done (but with a list comprehension), I was hoping there would be a more straightforward approach in Python, but seems there is not! Thank you for your answer!